# How coffee activates the nerve cells of the brain and what is the mechanism of it?

Tags: health, caffeine

After drinking coffee we feel so relaxed and our brains feel so free. Why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Caffeine blocks the adenosine methabolism in the neurons which normally manages the tiredness and sleep.**

[Here is a very nice informative video if you prefer to watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOfquPE1cnU).

Adenosine molecules are released by neurons during the day and after they reach some concentration, they activate the adenosine receptors of the neurons of our brains. This is a mechanism to stop us being extremely tired and makes us sleep regularly for daily maintenance of our body.

Caffeine is a very similar molecule to adenosine in the molecular scale. So, it tricks the receptors as if it is adenosine. But, it doesn't activate the sleeping procedure. So, as a result, we block our sleeping cycle by masquerading adenosine with caffeine for a while. After a while, caffeine is removed from our brain by blood flow and everything returns to normal.