# Am I psychologically addicted to coffee?

Tags: health, caffeine

I do not really mind if I am addicted to coffee. However, I noticed a psychological effect and that makes me kind of curious.

- When I do not drink coffee, I feel more negative about life. Caffeine really changes my mind in a positive direction.
- I can not really work without drinking coffee. After I get caffeine, I am more concentrated and this forces me to drink before I do some serious 'thinking' work.
- When I am sick, I avoid drinking coffee. However, I am experimenting myself in these situations. After I drink coffee, I feel a better improvement in my body compared to medicine.

Do you think I should be anxious?

Comment: Could you please check the [neural metabolism of caffeine](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/how-coffee-activates-the-nerve-cells-of-the-brain-and-what-is-the-mechanism-of-i/4489#4489), which may be somewhat relevant to understand your first question.

Comment: And,  How does that make you feel? When i snap my fingers you will awaken, you will not remember this conversation but every time someone says Coffee you will experience  a  warm fuzzy feeling of joy and a desire to have a cup of coffee.

Answer (score 2):

Studies show that caffeine withdrawal is more of a psychological than a biochemical phenomenon. For example, if we know that stopping the consumption of caffeine leads to headaches, they will happen, because waiting provokes a reaction. This, in particular, is evidenced by a review of the 2004 journal Psychopharmacology, in the preparation of which scientists analyzed more than 50 articles from medical literature on a given topic.

Answer (score 1):

yes you are addicted to coffee. coffee has caffeine inside of it which is an addictive drug. everything you have said in this post confirms your addiction. i don't think being addicted to anything is good. when you say anxious, do you mean anxious about your addiction or about using it to make you feel better when your sick. if your anxious about using when your sick, do what ever makes you feel better. if anxious about being addicted you probably should slow down on the consumption a little.